# How to write mathematically the triple operation and so on?

Tags: notation

We know that unary and binary opertions could be represened by symbolically $\: \circ x, \: y \circ z \quad$ respectively. How about the ones involve three and more.

Comment: $f(x,y,z)$ is one way.

Comment: When push comes to shove, function notation is always a safe bet. But, if you insist on infix notation, there are a few styles used for operators. See C's conditional operator, for example, which has the form $a?b:c$.

Comment: @DonThousand In fact, that example of a ternary operator [is often called](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/c/ternary-operator/) _the_ ternary operator, if only because programmers don't see many others often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have three elements or more to compose, it will become a little awkward to use a single mark between them to denote composition. It would be quite silly to, for example, arrange the inputs equidistantly around a single symbol.

At that rate, any operation can be written with functional notation much more easily: given the operation $F: X^n\to X$ you write $F(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ for the "product of $n$ elements."

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use an operator notation that implicitly has only a left side and a right side. Why not something like $\stackrel{y\;\;z}{x}$ instead?

Some actuarial notation has symbol decorations at every point of the compass. See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial_notation), for example.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sULa9Lc4pck) is a similar notation for a ternary relation, i.e. a boolean-returning ternary operator, an alternative to write $x^y=z$.